# Send newline char in urllib.quote in Django

Tags: python, django, newline, urllib

I'm trying to send two sentences (newline between them) using `urllib.quote` to Django template but unable to get the newline on template.
I've tried `.encode("utf-8")` and `%0A` but none of them working.

Here's my code:

```
# s = "Some string over here. %0A Some string there." 
s = "Some string over here. \n Some string there." 

WEBROOT = "{}://{}/mytemplate/?message={}".format(
                    protocol,
                    Site.objects.get_current(),
                    urllib.quote(
                        s.encode('utf8')
                    ),
                )
return HttpResponseRedirect(WEBROOT)
```

In Template:

```
 <div class="subtitle">
      {% if message %}
           <span>{{ message }}</span>
      {% else %}
            ....
      {% endif %}
 </div>
```

What I want:

```
Some string over here.  
Some string there.
```

What I'm getting:

```
Some string over here. \n Some string there.
```

or,

```
Some string over here. %0A Some string there.
```

Comment: The template is HTML. Newlines in HTML are `<br>` or if XHTML compatibility is desired: `<br />`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth <br> also doesn't works. It simply prints <br>